# how to get project path in hook script post-commit?(git)

Tags: git, path, post-commit

I want to call a Script that is located in the repository.

I could of course do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
../../myscript.sh
```

but I think thats not nice ;)

so how do I get the path of my project within the post-commit script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you're dealing with a non-bare repository, the `post-commit`<sup>1</sup> hook is run with a current working directory of the working tree of the repository.  So, you don't need the `../../`.

If you want the full path of the script, you could always do:

```
SCRIPT=$(readlink -nf myscript.sh)
```

... or you could use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get an absolute path to the working directory:

```
SCRIPT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/myscript.sh
```

<sup>1</sup> ... but note that this is not true of some other hooks, e.g. in a `post-receive` hook in a non-bare repository, the current working directory is the `.git` directory.

Comment: thank you. I did not know that it was already in the right directory, could have tried it before to figure it out by myself.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this still vaild?
my `post-commit` contains

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ./../../myscript.sh
```

and works.
Using just `exec myscript.sh` or `myscript.sh` doesn't work.

Moreover, even myscript.sh returns the /.git/hooks folder if asked for pwd.
Using $GIT_WORK_TREE points to ~. I currently see no robust way pointing to the repo root.