# How can we backup or clone GitoLite server on every commit

Tags: linux, git, gitolite

My firm is setting up Gitolite on Linux and we would like to setup a backup for the server just in case of a crash on every commit to a 2nd Linux server.

How can we backup a Gitolite server on every commit to it? Is anyone doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First you should not worry too much about git backups. - Everyone who is working in your project will have a complete clone on his box. - Hence more than enough backups. ;)

But you want to have another official repository updated after each push. In this case probably the easiest way is writing a small server side hook, that runs after each push and itself pushes the changes to the second repository.

You probably want to use a post-receive hook. For details have a look at [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) or [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

Example:

```
#create repositories
git init a
git init --bare b
git init --bare c

#add the hook in "b"
echo -e '#!/usr/bin/bash\nread old new ref\ngit push ../c $ref' >>b/hooks/post-receive
chmod +x b/hooks/post-receive

#create a commit in "a"
cd a
echo foo >test
git add .
git commit -m testcommit

#push it to "b"
git push ../b master
#notice the "remote:..." output of the hook

#find the commit in "c"
cd ../c
git log
```

This creates three repositories. When you have a commit in `a` and push it to `b` the hook will push it to `c`, too.

Comment: Have you seen any examples on how to do that anyway?

Comment: Just replace the local path by some remote or URL. Please have a look at `git help push`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to generate backups is to ask your post-receive hook to [create a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720366/6309) (a bit like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11369306/6309))

```
!/bin/sh

git bundle create "/path/to/backup/$(basename "$PWD").bundle"  --branches --tags
```

This is based on the fact that hook runs in a bare repo: see "[how to get project path in hook script post-commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248793/6309)".

The interest in **bundle and [`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)** is that is generates only ***one file***, which is easier to manage/copy around.
And that fact acts as a (mostly read-only) repo, meaning you can clone from that file.
This would work:

```
git clone myrepo.bundle myrepo
```

See also:

- "[`git bundle`: bundle tags and heads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720366/6309)",
- "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)", and
- "[Git with Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633346/6309)".

Comment: so this is not what I am looking for